# Execute dynamic SQL queries

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute a `SQL` like bellow inside a `SP`.

```
DECLARE
@varSearchQ VARCHAR(100),
@varFieldName VARCHAR(100),
@varTableName VARCHAR(100),
@Sql VARCHAR(Max)

SET @varSearchQ='000'
SET @varFieldName='varConsoleID'
SET @varTableName='FF.ConsoleDT'

SET @Sql = N'SELECT ' + @varFieldName + ' 
           FROM ' + @varTableName + ' 
           WHERE ' + @varFieldName + ' LIKE %' + @varSearchQ + '%'
```

I found a way like `EXEC sp_executesql @Sql`. But I'm getting errors.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Also: describe your task in a few words, so we could understand what may go wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> You Should Use `Print` for Debugging Statments

```
Create proc MYPROC
 as
 BEGIN


 DECLARE
    @varSearchQ VARCHAR(100),
    @varFieldName VARCHAR(100),
    @varTableName VARCHAR(100),
    @Sql VARCHAR(Max)

SET @varSearchQ='000'
SET @varFieldName='varConsoleID'
SET @varTableName='FF.ConsoleDT'

SET @Sql = N'SELECT ' + @varFieldName + ' 
           FROM ' + @varTableName + ' 
           WHERE ' + @varFieldName + ' LIKE ''%' + @varSearchQ + '%'''
           print  (@Sql)
           EXEC (@Sql)


 END
```

Comment: Thanks!. But I need that `sql` to be executed inside a `SP` and get the result to a Asp.Net project.

Comment: @SeevaliRathnayake you need to pass your parameters as input para to stored procedure

Comment: One point here is Ganesh has escaped out `LIKE ''%` (note the quote) which I believe is missing in the OP's question.